# Reentrancy of subclass overriding superclass

Tags: java.util.concurrent

I was reading book "Java concurrency in practice", the 2.3.2 Reentrancy. It says "*because the doSomething methods in Widget and LoggingWidget are both synchronized, each tries to acquire the lock on the Widget before proceeding*". I wonder why they all try to acquire the lock on the Widget, but not on the LoggingWidget.

```java
public class Widget{
    public synchronized void doSomething(){
        ...
    }
}

public class LoggingWidget extends Widget{
    public synchronized void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("calling doSomething");
        super.doSomething();
    }
}
```